# Forbid page break after the title in mdframed

Tags: mdframed

I use mdframed for my theorems like this

```
\mdfdefinestyle{theoremstyle}{%
  %adjustable lengths
  %inner margins
  innertopmargin=\topskip,
  % outter margins
  skipabove= 0.1in,
  skipbelow= 0.1in,
  % colrs
  linecolor=red!60,
  middlelinewidth=2pt,%
  roundcorner=5pt,
  apptotikzsetting={\tikzset{mdfframetitlebackground/.append style={%
  shade,left color=white, right color=blue!20}}},
  % Title
  frametitlefont=\TheoremHeaderFont\bfseries,
  frametitlerule=true,%
  frametitlerulecolor=orange!60,
  frametitlerulewidth=2pt,
  % Miscellaneous
  nobreak=false,
}
```

Sometimes page break occurs right after the theorem title.
How I can prevent to break the frame between title and content?

**EDIT BY yori**. I'm having the same problem, so here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.75in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{mdframed}[frametitle={The title}]%
\[
x^2+y^2=z^2.
\]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add a minimal, compilable example (MWE) that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: The issue is that when the frame start near the end of the page and page break occurs between the title and content of the frame. I want to prevent this from happening.

Comment: I know what the issue is, but it'll be a little hard for us to test that it works unless we have an example where it *doesn't*.

Comment: Please add a [full MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`, not just a snippet.

Comment: @Aradnix: I just added a MWE for itun because I'm having the same problem. I also added a working but slightly unsatisfactory solution.

Comment: One way to solve this problem is to use the `needspace` option, but this is a bit of an unsatisfactory solution, because it does not really express the intention, and it needs manual tweaking in the case of multi-line titles.

Comment: @Yori a better workaround would be to insert the `nobreak` option manually per-theorem when needed. Of course this would disallow pagebreaks in the middle of the box content.

Comment: @Bordaigorl: this is true but for large documents (I'm working on ~700 pages), this is quite tedious and not very robust. My current best solution is to not use `mdframed`'s title at all, and manually insert the title instead (in my own environment) and put a `\nobreak` after the title. This works well.

Comment: @Yori What is wrong with the `needspace` option?  If express it globally as `needspace=5\baselineskip` for the style you use for these boxes, then you will not have to tweak each environment.

Comment: @AndrewSwann: The value `x` for `needspace` has to be large enough so that the lines of the title + the first line of the contents is covered. On the one hand, I have mdframes with titles that take two lines, and that have contents that sometimes start with (display) equations. On the other hand, I have mdframes which have a title that fits on one line, and contents that fits on another. Setting `x` too low means breaking the first case, setting `x` too high leaves too much whitespace on the previous page. In my case, there is no value for `x` for which neither situation happens.

Answer (score 5):

**UNSATISFACTORY ANSWERS:**

One way to solve this problem is to use the `needspace` option:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.75in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{mdframed}[needspace=6em, frametitle={The title}]%
\[
x^2+y^2=z^2.
\]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

This tells `mdframed` to place the first page break at least 6em (vertically) into the frame. It is a bit of an unsatisfactory solution though, because it does not really express the intention, and it needs manual tweaking in the case of multi-line titles.

A second approach is to emulate the title, and add a `\nobreak` after the title:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.75in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-5]

\begin{mdframed}
\textbf{The title} \\ \nobreak
\[
x^2+y^2=z^2.
\]
\end{mdframed}

\end{document}
```

This works better, but still breaks in certain cases...